# PostgreSQL use UPDATE ON CONFLICT INSERT

Tags: postgresql, insert-update

I have a table in postgres with hundreds of rows with distinct keys.

I know that I will update the values for each key frequently, but initially I have to insert a first value.

Now I think it is quite ***ineffective*** to use `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE` since I know the full lifetime there will only be updates. Is there any way to apply `UPDATE ... ON CONFLICT INSERT` or are both approaches equally effective (what I don't think so).

Comment: `INSERT .. ON CONFLICT` isn't really slower than just an UPDATE even if you never really INSERT

Comment: Ok, since it seems to be the only "short" way to do it, I hope you are right ;)

Comment: Single-row updates or batch updates? But first (*always*): your version of Postgres?